# Upload img to firebase storage + create new bucket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Self taught coder here. Hopefully I can explain this properly. I'm trying to create a recipe website where a user can upload their own custom recipe with images. The user submits a form and the info uploads to a database collection 'guides'. How does the file being uploaded to firebase storage send back a URL to react so that the form can record the URL into the steps array?

This is the logic for user to upload img in the form, inside Upload component:

```
    const uploadFile = () => {
      const name = new Date().getTime() + file.name
      const storageRef = ref(storage, file.name)

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  (snapshot) => {
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    setPercentage(progress)
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case 'paused':
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case 'running':
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
        default: 
          break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  }, 
  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      setData((prev) => ({...prev, img: downloadURL}))
    });
  }
);

    }
    file && uploadFile();
  }, [file]);
```

Here is the logic to upload/submit form also inside the Upload component.

```
  const handleAddGuide = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newId = uuidv4()

    await setDoc(doc(db, "guides", newId), {
      author: e.target.author.value,
      categoryId: "100",
      categoryName: e.target.categoryName.value,
      // coverImg: imgURL,
      id: newId,
      name: e.target.name.value,
      tags: e.target.tags.value,
      steps: [
        {
          step: e.target.step.value,
          img: file.url <---- I need this file to upload to a folder inside storage named dynamically after the name of the recipe ("e.target.name.value").
        }
      ]
    });
  };
```

And this is where I initialize db and storage:

```
firebase.js 

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/storage"
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  <details> 
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const userAuth = getAuth()
export const db = getFirestore(app)
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

Comment: Just keep the download link in the global variable for the time that user hits submit and then reference it in the array. Also you mentioned that you want the folder name to be same as that of the recipe name for the image, for this you have to change the filename to `recipename/time-filename` in the storage ref.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Can I do ```const storageRef = ref(storage, `${recipename}/${time-filename}`) ``` I need the names to be dynamic since every user will upload a unique recipe name.

Comment: yeah! you can do that